# Choosing audio format when saving data locally on a web app

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-audio

I have a web app getting some audio recording input from the user.
And there is a button to save it locally as an audio file.
The resulting file I am getting is of ogg-opus format. Concretely when I use the file command I get this in the terminal:

```
MyMac$ file Clip.wav 
Clip.wav: Ogg data, Opus audio,
MyMac$
```

I can check that the recording is all right using VLC.
On the other hand I can't play the file with afplay as is normally possible with an *mp3*, *m4a*  or *wav* file.

```
MyMac$ afplay Clip.wav
Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('typ?')
MyMac$
```

Here follows my relevant code:

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  // getUserMedia is supported.
  const constraints = { audio: true };
  let chunks = [];

  let onSuccess = function(stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    visualize(stream);
    ........

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      ........
      audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
      ........
      audio.controls = true;
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav;codecs=0' });
      chunks = [];
      ........
      upload.addEventListener("click", 
        function(event) {loadToServer(blob)})
      ........
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  }

  let onError = function(err) {
    console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}
```

I would like to know how to change my code in order to generate a proper *wav* file or even *mp3*.

Note:

I have made trials modifying this line of code:

```
const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav;codecs=0' });
```

in various ways, but is has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

In order to specify the mimeType of your recording you need to tell the `MediaRecorder` which mimeType you prefer before it starts the recording.

```
- const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
+ const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/wav' });
```

Unfortunately `audio/wav` is not supported by any browser. You will get an error when trying the snippet above.

Since I needed wav recordings as well I built a library which is meant to add this functionality. It's called [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder) because it could be extended with any other (audio) codec you like.

If you don't want to use a third party library and keep the browser using the codec it likes best you can save your file like this in order to get a valid file with the correct suffix.

```
- const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav;codecs=0' });
+ const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : mediaRecorder.mimeType });
```

The suffix would then be the portion of the type after the slash and before a possible semicolon.

Here is an example of a full HTML document that uses jspm to load extendable-media-recorder without a bundler.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="start" disabled>start</button>
        <button id="stop" disabled>stop</button>
        <script type="module">
            import { MediaRecorder, register } from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder';
            import { connect } from 'https://jspm.dev/extendable-media-recorder-wav-encoder';

            const $start = document.getElementById('start');
            const $stop = document.getElementById('stop');

            await register(await connect());

            const chunks = [];
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            const mediaRecoder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/wav' });

            mediaRecoder.addEventListener('dataavailable', ({ data }) => {
                chunks.push(data);
            });
            mediaRecoder.addEventListener('stop', ({ data }) => {
                const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type : mediaRecoder.mimeType });

                console.log(blob);
            });

            $start.addEventListener('click', () => {
                mediaRecoder.start();

                $stop.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    $stop.disabled = true;

                    mediaRecoder.stop();
                });

                $start.disabled = true;
                $stop.disabled = false;
            });

            $start.disabled = false;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get an error on the first line following your suggestion:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: MediaRecorder constructor: audio/wav indicates an unsupported container

Comment: I certainly want to keep in mind your library for future use. But this time I am trying to avoid any third party addition. I'd like to keep it as plain HTML/JS. This is not a node.js app.

Comment: Yes, as I said above no browser supports `audio/wav`. Therefore every browser will throw an error when you set the mimeType to `audio/wav`. I'll update the answer to point this out more clearly. The only way I know of to get PCM data out of the native `MediaRecorder` is to use `audio/webm;codecs=pcm`. But this only works in Chromium based browsers. It's what extendable-media-recorder uses internally.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood your comment then. So there is not way for me to end up with a .wav file, unless I do something more involved; right? If I make a NodeJS app, using your library; that would do what I need. Tell me if I am wrong please.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I guess if you don't use a library to record wav files in the browser you would end up with your own library in the end. That's what happened to me. :-) The backend technology doesn't really matter. extendable-media-recorder runs in the browser.

Comment: I see. I was mentioning NodeJS because, taking a quick look at extendable-media-recorder, I see that it is installed with npm. And I have never used npm outside of NodeJS. I need to take a closer look at you library and see how I can use it (in the simplest possible way).

Comment: I have decided to give a try to your library. But my knowledge of npm being limited to NodeJS on Heroku. I am kind of lost when using it on a server where I usually only upload plain HTML, possibly with some JS or where I use PHP. I have never done anything on this server with node or npm, so I am not quite confident on what to upload for things to work. I have locally created an npm project, starting with npm init and then installed extendable-media-recorder. Then I made a bare-bone index.js and uploaded the whole thing.

Comment: But my browser is only getting the index.js as plain text, so I guess I must be missing something.

Comment: npm was traditionally only for packages that were meant to run on Node.js. Hence the name node package manager. But nowerdays it contains also a lot of packages which are meant to run in the browser. Typically they get used together with a bundler like webpack to prepare them for being used in the browser. I see that this is all very confusing at first. Luckily there are services like jspm which do all this behind the scenes. I added an example to my answer which uses jspm to load the packages directly in the browser.